# Hide text from the navigation bar in the first frame

Tags: beamer

I hope you're doing great. When I using beamer, how can I set the first frame, with the respective navigation bar but without text (only with the rectangle located above).

Best regards

Comment: Well, this certainly depends on the theme. Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 2):

Of course this answer is completely speculative, as you did not provide any information about your beamer document. But maybe you could simply colour the text in the colour of the background.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}

{
    \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{use=palette tertiary, fg=palette tertiary.bg}
    \setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{use=palette secondary, fg=palette secondary.bg}    
    \begin{frame}
        empty header
    \end{frame}
}

    \section{bla}
    \subsection{blub}

    \begin{frame}
        abc
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]