# Hide navigation text in the first frame using beamer

Tags: beamer, navigation

I'm trying to work using Beamer, but I don't know how can I hide only the navigation text, but keeping the respective above rectangles. According to the figure I uploaded, the first frame is my actual situation, but what I want to do are presented in the second frame. The third frame, is ok. I only want to hide the navigation text (keeping the respectives rectangles) in the first frame (or titlepage):

[image]

That is my code, using the theme "warsaw":

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,t]{beamer}
\definecolor{mikadoyellow}{rgb}{1.0, 0.77, 0.05}
\definecolor{yaleblue}{rgb}{0.06, 0.3, 0.57}
\usetheme{warsaw}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{family=\sffamily}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}{family=\sffamily}
\setbeamerfont{author in head/foot}{family=\sffamily}
\setbeamerfont{title in head/foot}{family=\sffamily}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=mikadoyellow}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=yaleblue}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\justifying
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\textunderscript}[1]{$_{\text{#1}}$}

\title[Title 2]{Title 1}   
\author{Author} 
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\sloppy

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}\frame{\frametitle{Section 1}}
\section{Section 2}\frame{\frametitle{Section 2}}
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Subsection 1}\frame{\frametitle{Section 3-1}}
\subsection{Subsection 2}\frame{\frametitle{Section 3-2}}
\subsection{Subsection 3}\frame{\frametitle{Section 3-3}}
\section{Section 4}
\subsection{Subsection 1}\frame{\frametitle{Section 4-1}}
\subsection{Subsection 2}\frame{\frametitle{Section 4-2}}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324552/hide-text-from-the-navigation-bar-in-the-first-frame/324582#324582

Comment: But this also removes the author in the footline - I have a different idea.

Comment: Thanks, but the above left background is valeblue, but it doesn't exist this same color for the font. What could I do?

Comment: I am sorry, but what do you mean by "doesn't exist this same color for the font"? As you used yaleblue for the background of `palette quaternary`, I took that for my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to just colour the navigation text in the same colour as the background - voilà: spirited away!

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,t]{beamer}
\definecolor{mikadoyellow}{rgb}{1.0, 0.77, 0.05}
\definecolor{yaleblue}{rgb}{0.06, 0.3, 0.57}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{family=\sffamily}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}{family=\sffamily}
\setbeamerfont{author in head/foot}{family=\sffamily}
\setbeamerfont{title in head/foot}{family=\sffamily}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=mikadoyellow}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=yaleblue}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\justifying
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\textunderscript}[1]{$_{\text{#1}}$}

\title[Title 2]{Title 1}   
\author{Author} 
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \sloppy

    {
        \addtobeamertemplate{headline}{%
            \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{use=palette quaternary, fg=palette quaternary.bg}
    }{}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
}

    \section{Section 1}\frame{\frametitle{Section 1}}
    \section{Section 2}\frame{\frametitle{Section 2}}
    \section{Section 3}
    \subsection{Subsection 1}\frame{\frametitle{Section 3-1}}
    \subsection{Subsection 2}\frame{\frametitle{Section 3-2}}
    \subsection{Subsection 3}\frame{\frametitle{Section 3-3}}
    \section{Section 4}
    \subsection{Subsection 1}\frame{\frametitle{Section 4-1}}
    \subsection{Subsection 2}\frame{\frametitle{Section 4-2}}
\end{document}
```

[image]