# beamer - change titlepage not to show details in headline/footline

Tags: beamer, header-footer, titles

I am using the `Berlin` theme to create a presentation with beamer. I like the fact that the `headline` and `footline` show the navigation, author, etc, but I would like to hide that information on the titleslide, as it is already displayed there, and have it appear again on all following slides.

I, however, do **not** want to lose the head- and footline themselves (using `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}` for example just makes the whole headline disappear).

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59631/hide-navigation-information-in-sidebar-on-title-page-and-toc-page-beamer) is somewhat similar to mine, but I tried modifying the code showed there, which did not work for me (see MWE below).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Title}
\author{Jane Doe}
\institute{University of Foo}
\date{\today}

% Beamer setup
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\renewcommand*{\slideentry}[6]{} % hide subsection bullets and remove space

\begin{document}

%\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\frame{\titlepage}

%\setbeamertemplate{headline}[headline theme]
\section{Test}
\begin{frame}
  Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\frame[plain]{\titlepage}` ?

Comment: @Zarko That removes the whole head- and footline. I want to keep the coloured bars, only get rid of the information displayed within.

Comment: Sorry, not read your question enough carefully ... Maybe some one here know how to solve your problem, however suggested solution is to my opinion more nice as empty headers and footers .)

Comment: @Zarko I know it's a matter of taste, but I quite like the coloured bars :) But if no one knows a better solution, I will resort to `plain`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing all trouble to acutually remove the information from head/footline, it can simply be hidden by setting the font colour equal to the background colour.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Title}
\author{Jane Doe}
\institute{University of Foo}
\date{\today}

% Beamer setup
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\renewcommand*{\slideentry}[6]{} % hide subsection bullets and remove space

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{use=palette secondary, fg=palette secondary.bg} 
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{use=palette tertiary, fg=palette tertiary.bg} 
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{use=palette tertiary, fg=palette tertiary.bg}
\frame{\titlepage}
}

%\setbeamertemplate{headline}[headline theme]
\section{Test}
\begin{frame}
  Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @samcarter you could use the more general and therefore better solution of your older answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324582/123129) (witch was linked in the new answer below). That is: `\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{use=palette secondary, fg=palette secondary.bg}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{use=palette tertiary, fg=palette tertiary.bg}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{use=palette tertiary, fg=palette tertiary.bg}`. Btw. you marked the older question as a duplicate of the newer.

Comment: @dexteritas edited, thanks for the suggestion. The other question was quite unclear, it did not include any information on the theme and the OP never gave feedback, while this one is a good and clear question, so I decided to mark the unclear question as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code from this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324552/hide-text-from-the-navigation-bar-in-the-first-frame?rq=1)

```
{
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{use=palette tertiary, fg=palette tertiary.bg}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{use=palette secondary, fg=palette secondary.bg}    
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
}
```