# Editing footline of the title page in CambridgeUS template

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I am trying to eliminate all the text in the footline of the title page in CambridgeUS beamer template. I do not want to use a plain frame.
I tried to modify the template using `\setbeamertemplate`, but I learnt that it applies to the document as a whole.

I also tried using `\setbeamertemplate{title page}{footline}{}`, but the output is just footline on the title page, aligned to the center-left.

Anyway that I can edit the footline of title page only?

P.S. I'm new to TEX.

Comment: [How to remove footline on the title page of beamer slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18828/134144) might be interesting.

Comment: Locally using `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{} ` just for the title frame as in the following example should be sufficient in order to remove the foot line from the title frame only: `\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{} 
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
regular frame
\end{frame}
\end{document}`

Comment: I'll try them out, thanks! 
Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: It worked, the footline is now completely removed. Is there a way to retain the color boxes there?

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted your question as you wanting to remove the entire fooline as opposed to just removing the text. For the latter, [beamer - change titlepage not to show details in headline/footline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338860/134144) might be useful.